# How to Store data permanently in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am on a Timer project that takes a value from a variable through unwind segue to pass it to another view controller, then append its value to an Array that should be used to insert a row with the task name whenever the user pressed save button I need to save the result permanently, but I am confused which data should I save the value of the variable itself, the row, or the array?

```
var taskList = [String]()

@IBAction func saveToTaskList (segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    let newItemViewController = segue.source as! AddTaskTableViewController
    let name = newItemViewController.itemName
    let date = newItemViewController.date

    print("itemName passed is: \(name)")

    if name == "" {

    }
    else {
        print(date)
        taskList.append(name!)
        let indexToInsert = taskList.count == 0 ? 0 : taskList.count - 1
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: indexToInsert, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    }

}
```

[add task view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSAFB.png)
[Timer / Task List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaWBp.png)

Comment: I'd suggest storing them as an array. So if you are using an object for each task, you'd store an array of those objects.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to the hint of [Matt Le Fleur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/810167/matt-le-fleur)
I solved the issue by using objects as below:

```
    @IBAction func saveToTaskList (segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    let newItemViewController = segue.source as! AddTaskTableViewController
    var name = newItemViewController.itemName
    let date = newItemViewController.date

    let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")

    var items:[String]

    if let tempItems = itemsObject as? [String] {

        items = tempItems

        items.append(name!)

        print(items)

    } else {

        items = [name!]

    }

    UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")

    name = ""

}
```

Then added a ViewDidAppear as below:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")


    if let tempItems = itemsObject as? [String] {

        items = tempItems

    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```